# How to get negetive of a complex where clause in mongo db

Tags: pymongo

I have a mongo db complex filter generated dynamically which might look like

```
where_condition = {"$and":[{"column_3": "Offer"}, {"column_2":"MSN"}]}
collection.find(where_condition)
```

The condition might have unknown depth in `$and` and `$or`

Is it possible to find the negative of the where_condition

This does not work

```
not_condition = {"$not": where_condition}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use $nor. Something like this:

```
where_condition = {"$and":[{"column_3": "Offer"}, {"column_2":"MSN"}]}
not_condition = {"$nor":[{"column_3": "Offer"}, {"column_2":"MSN"}]}
```

You can find some more info on the mongodb doc for [$nor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/nor/).

Comment: But the where condition is not something that I know. It is generated from the UI and comes in depending on the type of operation performed. If I knew what where condition I could have written the negative of it easily.

Comment: It also can have infinite nesting of AND's and OR's.